# Classic ASP + stored procedure throwing error

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have a very simple call of a stored procedure right here:

```
sql = "exec P_KB_GET_GK_UEBERSICHT '" & request("status") & "','" & request("jahr") & "','" & request("gkcl_vnr") & "','" & request("gkcl_name") & "','" & session("sgi") & "','" &_
            request("gk_nr") & "','" & request("gk_name") & "','" & request("gueltjahr") & "'"
```

This yields a result like this:

```
exec P_KB_GET_GK_UEBERSICHT '','','','','D2335548','','','2017'
```

When I run this command in my SQL Server Management Studio, I get my output like expected.

However, in my ASP file, I get an error, which I apparently can only provide in german, since I can't adjust the output language (due to missing privileges):

> COM ERROR NR: -2147217913 (0x80040E07)
>
> Fehler beim Konvertieren des varchar-Werts 'diverse' in den int-Datentyp

Which basically translates to: error while converting the varchar-value "diverse" into `int`. This is where I'm totally stuck. I have NO idea where this is coming from.

For the case of providing as much as possible, please see the stored procedure as well:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_KB_GET_GK_UEBERSICHT]
    @status TINYINT, 
    @jahr INT, 
    @cl_vnr BIGINT, 
    @cl_name NVARCHAR(50), 
    @sgi NVARCHAR(20), 
    @gknr NVARCHAR(4), 
    @gkname VARCHAR(50), 
    @gueltjahr INT
AS

if @cl_vnr IS NULL set @cl_vnr = 0
if @status = NULL set @status = 0
if @jahr IS NULL set @jahr = 0
if @gueltjahr IS NULL set @gueltjahr = 0
if @gknr = '' set @gknr = '0'
if @gknr IS NULL set @gknr = '0'

if @gueltjahr = 0
    select distinct CL_ID, CD_CLVID, CD_VERSION, CL_NAME, CD_JAHR, ST_NAME as CD_STATUS,
    case isNULL(CD_AKTIV,0) when 0 then 'Nein' when 1 then 'Ja' end as CD_AKTIV,
    CD_STATUS as CD_STATUS_ID, CD_VON, CD_BIS 
from dbo.V_KB_CLUSTER d
inner join dbo.V_KB_CLUSTER_GK k on d.CD_CLVID = k.KD_CLVID
left join dbo.T_KB_GK_STATUS on CD_STATUS = ST_ID
where   d.CL_ART = 'GK'
        and CD_STATUS = case when @status = 0 then CD_STATUS else @status end
        and CD_JAHR = case when @jahr = 0 then CD_JAHR else @jahr end
        and CD_CLVID = case when @cl_vnr = 0 then CD_CLVID else @cl_vnr end
        and CL_NAME like '%' + @cl_name + '%'
        and k.KD_NR = case when @gknr = '0' then k.KD_NR else @gknr end
        and k.GK_KUNDE like '%' + @gkname + '%'
order by CL_ID, CD_JAHR DESC, CD_VERSION DESC
else
    select distinct CL_ID, CD_CLVID, CD_VERSION, CL_NAME, CD_JAHR, ST_NAME as CD_STATUS,
    case isNULL(CD_AKTIV,0) when 0 then 'Nein' when 1 then 'Ja' end as CD_AKTIV,
    CD_STATUS as CD_STATUS_ID, CD_VON, CD_BIS 
from dbo.V_KB_CLUSTER d
inner join dbo.V_KB_CLUSTER_GK k on d.CD_CLVID = k.KD_CLVID
left join dbo.T_KB_GK_STATUS on CD_STATUS = ST_ID
where   d.CL_ART = 'GK'
        and CD_STATUS = case when @status = 0 then CD_STATUS else @status end
        and CD_JAHR = case when @jahr = 0 then CD_JAHR else @jahr end
        and CD_CLVID = case when @cl_vnr = 0 then CD_CLVID else @cl_vnr end
        and CL_NAME like '%' + @cl_name + '%'
        and k.KD_NR = case when @gknr = '0' then k.KD_NR else @gknr end
        and k.GK_KUNDE like '%' + @gkname + '%'
        and @gueltjahr between year(CD_VON) and isNULL(year(CD_BIS),@gueltjahr)
order by CL_ID, CD_JAHR DESC, CD_VERSION DESC
```

I have literally hundreds of other stored procedures which don't cause this problem right here. There is also no column called `diverse`.

**Kinda solved**

So I figured out, that I had to use `'0'` instead of `0` in my definition right here:

```
if @jahr IS NULL set @jahr = '0'
```

I don't understand why that is though. It is definetly marked as an INT, an INT is the parameter (2017 for example) and the field-definition is INT as well. Can someone explain what this is?

Comment: You desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. You have the textbook example of sql injection. My friend bobby tables loves code like this. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: For the issue at hand it is nearly impossible to distinguish the actual issue without a lot more detail about your tables and such.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm totally with you. In my defence though: I didn't do these queries initially and everytime I try to convince people here to re-do it, the same argument comes up every time: "we don't have time / resources for that". But as I said, I'm totally on your side!

Comment: Then ask them when they plan on having time to rebuild the entire database or possibly even the server. When code is written like that it is not a matter of if it happens, it is a matter of when. I understand it would be impossible to schedule time for somebody to do that full time but it should be mandatory that when you open some code and it building up a string to execute that it should be fixed. I know if that was me I would just fix them when I encounter them.